# Global IPv6 adrress is unable to bind on Solaris

Tags: c, ipv6

I am trying to bring up a sample code for IPv6 server on Solaris. When i give link local address, it is working fine. But when i give global address, it is failing to bind. Please tell me, that can we use global IPv6 address on Solaris ?

This is my code ....

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/* the port users will be connecting to */

#define MYPORT 9000

/* how many pending connections queue will hold */

#define BACKLOG 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])

{

/* listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd */
int sockfd, new_fd;

/* my address information */struct sockaddr_in6 their_addr;
socklen_t sin_size;

//struct sigaction sa;
int yes = 1;

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
{
    perror("Server-socket() error lol!");
    return 0;//exit(1);
}
else
printf("Server-socket() sockfd is OK...\n");

if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
{
    perror("Server-setsockopt() error lol!");
    return 0;//exit(1);
}else
    printf("Server-setsockopt is OK...\n");



/* host byte order */
my_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;

/* short, network byte order */
my_addr.sin6_port = htons(MYPORT);

/* automatically fill with my IP */
 inet_pton(AF_INET6,"2345:1111:aaaa::500",&my_addr.sin6_addr);
//inet_pton(AF_INET6,"fe80::203:baff:fe50:cbe5",&my_addr.sin6_addr);
my_addr.sin6_scope_id=5;

/* zero the rest of the struct */

if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1)
    perror("Server-bind() error");
    return 0;//exit(1);
}
else
    printf("Server-bind() is OK...\n");

if(listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1)
{
    perror("Server-listen() error");
    return 0;//exit(1);
}
printf("Server-listen() is OK...Listening...\n");

sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);

if((new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) == -1)
{
    perror("Server-accept() error");
    //continue;
}
else
    printf("Server-accept() is OK...\n");

printf("Server-new socket, new_fd is OK...\n");
printf("Server: Got connection from \n");

/* this is the child process */

/* child doesn’t need the listener */
char buf[1024];
int numbytes=0;
if((numbytes = recv(new_fd, buf, 1024, 0)) == -1)
{
    perror("recv()");
    return 1;//exit(1);
}
else
    printf("Client-The recv() is OK...\n");

buf[numbytes] = '\0';printf("Client-Received: %s", buf);
if(send(new_fd, "This is a test string from server!\n", 37, 0) == -1)
        perror("Server-send() error lol!");

/* parent doesn’t need this*/
close(new_fd);
printf("Server-new socket, new_fd closed successfully...\n");
return 0;
}
```

Thank you ....

Comment: Try without setting the scope id.

Comment: Without scope id also it is not working ....

Comment: Your code doesn’t even compile in the first place, let alone debugging what’s wrong with it. Honestly looks like it’s written by a 14-year-old.

Answer (score 1):

Is `2345:1111:aaaa::500` configured on any of your interfaces? This is required before you can bind to that address.

Comment: Yes skjaidev, 2345:1111:aaaa::500 is the IP address of my box with eth0.   bge0: flags=2000841<UP,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv6> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet6 fe80::203:baff:fe50:cbe5/10
        ether 0:3:ba:50:cb:e5
bge0:1: flags=20a0841<UP,RUNNING,MULTICAST,NOLOCAL,ADDRCONF,IPv6> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet6 subnet 2345:1111:aaaa::500/120

Answer (score 1):

2345:1111:aaaa::500 is the netmask, the IP is fe80::203:baff:fe50:cbe5

I think you will need scope id (2) to bind() to work, since it´s a Link-Local IPv6 address.

- Malleus

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about on the Solaris, but on Windows 7 it requires Administrator priviledges to bind a socket to a global or multicast address.

Can you run your test with elevated priviledges?

-Jesse

Comment: Thanks for your response Jesse